# Lighttpd configuration, . (dots) in my query string cause 404

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony1, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I have an address on my site like so:

http://www.example.com/lookup?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgigaom.com%2F2010%2F10%2F10%2Fangry-birds-for-windows7-phone-dont-count-on-it%2F

In this example, the dot in the 'gigaom.com' part of the query string is screwing with lighttpd and my rewrite rules. I get a 404 with the dot in, no 404 if I take the dot out. My rewrite rules are below. In case it makes a difference, I'm using symfony 1.4.

If anyone could shed some light on this problem it would be much appreciated!

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/(.*\..+)$" => "$0",
    "^/(.*)\.(.*)"    => "/index.php",
    "^/([^.]+)$"      => "/index.php/$1",
    "^/$"             => "/index.php"
  )
```

**For anyone having trouble with lighttpd and symfony (I know you're out there, cause there are plenty of unresolved threads on the issue) I ended up solving and answering it below.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK so after much debugging with the help of:

```
debug.log-request-handling = "enable"
```

^^ This is a lifesaver for when you're trying to debug rewrite rules in lighttpd! (it logged everything for me to /var/log/lighttpd/error.log)

I've figured it out. For all those people having trouble getting symfony to work with lighttpd (including the dot problem!) here's a working set of rules:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/(js|images|uploads|css|sf)/(.*)" => "$0", # we want to load these assets as is, without index.php
    "^/[a-zA-Z_-]+\.(html|txt|ico)$" => "$0", # for any static .html files you might be calling in your web root, we don't want to put the index.php controller in front of them
    "^/sf[A-z]+Plugin.*" => "$0", # don't want to mess with plugin routes
    "^/([a-z_]+)\.php(.*)\.(.*)$" => "/$1.php$2.$3", # same concept as rules below, except for other applications/environments (backend.php, backend_dev.php, etc)
    "^/([a-z_]+)\.php([^.]*)$" => "/$1.php$2", # see comment right above this one
    "^/(.*)\.(.*)$"    => "/index.php/$1.$2", # handle query strings and the dot problem!
    "^/([^.]+)$"      => "/index.php/$1", # general requests
    "^/$"             => "/index.php" # the home page
  )
```

If anyone has more trouble, post here. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if there are two dots in the query, 'www.gigaom.com'?

Comment: Just tried it, it works. I've also updated the rules for a bunch of other cases I've discovered over the past hour (other applications like backend.php for instance) and plugin files. The only thing I have left to resolve is capital letters, like backend.php/News as a route.

Comment: any idea how i could get this case? http://2famous.tv/2013/07/11/adrian-layals-radio-show-episode-6-2/?fb_action_ids=10153032356450061&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%2210153032356450061%22%3A528698340513393%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210153032356450061%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

Comment: the dot line doesn't work for me. then again, i too have two dots. so how was that written again?

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHP, MySQL, and .htaccess file for rewriting rules. Just sharing so others can also benefit.

My previous rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+).html$ detail.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

It was working with this result: http://www.sitecliff.com/Yahoo-UK/4.html

I wanted the website name instead of the title in the url. After surfing the net, I figured out that the dot is causing the problem as you mentioned above.

```
"^/(.*)\.(.*)$"    => "/index.php/$1.$2", # handle query strings and the dot problem!
```

So I changed the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ detail.php?url=$1 [L]
```

After this, I got my desired result: http://www.sitecliff.com/yahoo.com

Comment: This is OT and incorrect: The answer is for Apache not for lighthttpd. Dots should be escaped by backslash `\.` if they are important, not blindly removed.