# Cant get requested GET param in yii

Tags: url, yii, get, param

im trying create url like this: `www.domain.com/auth?join=social` in yii.
This is my config:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
     'rules' => array(
        '<action:(auth)>' => 'site/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
     ),
     'showScriptName'=>false,
),
```

when i calling this: `www.domain.com/auth?join=social` page i cant get param: `join`. But when i calling `www.domain.com/index.php/auth?join=social` i can get. 
im getting param with this code: `$social = Yii::app()->request->getParam('join');`. Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my error it wasnt error YII. I must be write rewrite rules in lighttpd configurations. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965651/lighttpd-configuration-dots-in-my-query-string-cause-404) explained very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
$social = Yii::app()->request->getParam('social');
```

change it with

```
$social = Yii::app()->request->getParam('join');
```

Comment: Ups its my error. In my code was join. When i wrote this question than i wrote incorrect. Okay its not problem im using lighty maybe there something wrong? what do you think?

Comment: I dont know but maybe '<action:(auth)>' => 'site/<action:\w+>', will fix the problem. Can you try this.

Comment: Burhan Çetin thank you to your answers. I found my error. Im using lighty server. there are not works htaccess file. and i configure url.rewrite and it works. Teşekkür ederim!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$_REQUEST['join']
```

in your action.